# How to remove <a href> </a> color of link?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am getting NSString as

```
 <a href="http://www.googel.com.com/index.php?route=common/search" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

In UIWebView, it looks like blue color.

I either want to remove blue color or simply remove this TAG.

I removed link check from XIB Attribute Inspector, but it only detects as

```
www.google.com
```

How can I do it.

Thanks

Comment: Could you not use `stringByEvaluatingJavascript:` to run some css using javascript to remove that link or change the color? Can you change the html itself without using objective-c?

Comment: if you dont want any of the links/phone number etc to be clickable on your UIWebView, you can use `dataDetectorTypes` of `UIWebView` and set it to `UIDataDetectorTypeNone`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS 7 you can set the tintColor of UIWebView. It affects the datadetector link color:

```
[yourWebView setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

So you can make it the same color as your text.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a NSString with html content you can always append a html script tag to the original html and use css to style your content any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

**solution 1: Remove anchor text color**

Append following to the string received

```
a:link, a:hover, a:active { color: black; }
```

**Solution 2: remove Anchor tag**

for this you can write (or can search on google) Regex for removeing anchor tag